# Raspian buster lite: grep fails with "Illegal instruction"

Tags: raspbian-buster

Suddenly, grep has begun failing.

cat test.txt | grep hello

generates an "Illegal instruction" error. It makes no difference what's being piped in nor what PATTERN I use.

- cat test.txt | less
- grep
- grep -V
- grep --help

all work fine

I've done a update and upgrade. How do I fix this?

Comment: `cat test.txt | less grep` that won't run - so, what is the output of `grep -V` - also which Rpi do you have. I have no issue with grep in Rpi3/4 - but I've had issues with other programs in RPi1 with illegal instruction error that doesn't occur in Rpi3/4

Comment: @MACE surely you mean `cat test.txt | less grep` is the command which doesn't work, and  `cat test.txt | grep hello` is one of the ones which "work fine"?

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't realize the formatting of the question was off.  I've edited the question.

Comment: @JaromandaX I have a Zero WH.  Three other Zeros are working fine.

Comment: Is this the same Zero WH that's giving the DHCP problem? If so, have you re-flashed the SD card?

Comment: @Seamus, yes, it's the same device.  I did end up flashing the SD and all the issues are gone.  I was hoping for a less dramatic option.

Comment: Use `grep hello test.txt`.

Comment: @MACE: Happy to hear you're squared away for now. This is just a guess, but new SD cards and re-flashed SD cards may cure 20% of all questions on this site. Also note @Ingo's comment above... he's a smart guy; know that `grep` is perfectly capable of processing a file - you don't have to "feed" `grep` through a `pipe`. See `man grep` from the CLI  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SD card got corrupted.  Recreated and all works fine.  Not sure how to prevent it in the future.  Possibly related to the power.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same "illegal instruction" doing some other operation on my RPi 2B, but also some corrupted files on the micro SD card. While fiddling with these problems, I spotted many "Under-voltage" error in system log (see `sudo journalctl`)and a red LED glowing that I didn't noticed earlier.

So I replaced my power supply that did well for years with my old RPi mod B and all errors went away.